# In react native project homestack route does not show anything

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes

I started creating review app where I need to use navigation

The project does not show any error but, it does not show anything on the android emulator , when it have to show the Home screen .
please help me solve this problem. it is a small project so please help
here is the code : https://github.com/sabaPhruidze/ReviewApplication

I hope you solve this problem and explain it so in the future I can do it independently

Comment: You wrapped the stack navigaor with `<GestureHandlerRootView>`. As the document in [react-native-gesture-handler](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/guides/migrating-off-rnghenabledroot/#update-your-js-code), you should add `style={{flex:1}}` to the component in order to fill the screen.